# java.lang.T : Can't find this type

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

I was hovering over the method **asList()** in class java.util.Arrays when I suddenly hovered over the following(as shown in the screenshot)

[image]

The javadoc showed the type **java.util.T extends java.lang.Object** but I couldn't find the class definition of T in java.util. What is happening here?
Pardon me if I am asking a silly question(If it is I shall delete it). Right now I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is a generic type parameter. There is no such class `java.util.T`.

BTW, when I hover in Eclipse over the `T` in `asList(T... a)`, it shows for some reason `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T`. This makes no sense. I guess it's a bug in the IDE.

Comment: It is not a bug in Eclipse, it happens in IntelliJ as well. The guys from Apache POI choose a really bad name for their class.

Answer (score 1):

`T` is the alias of a generic parameter, which has a method-scope (i.e. valid in the context of the method).

During the compilation process, this `T` will be **replaced** with a specific type.

For example, if you do the following thing:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
```

`T` will be replaced with `String`.

This feature provides *flexibility* to the code you write and *reliefs* us from the burden of *overloading* methods with different/incompatible parameter types.

More info:

- [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Technically it'll be replaced at compile time, not runtime, since Java generics are a compiler only feature.

Comment: The confusion arose actually from the fact that JavaDoc shows "the name of the package in which the hovered type is" for all the types except this. In this case, it displayed the package it is in. Its not like I am not familiar with Generics but, you know sometimes silly things bug for nothing and thats why I said "If it is a silly question" in the question

Answer (score 1):

T extends Object is not a Class it's a Generic. Take a look a [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)